# disable textbox to enter values

Tags: jquery

I have textbox with datepicker. according to my requirement user must select either first tuesday or second tuesday of the month. So i disabled the rest of the dates using following code and its working fine.

```
var dates_allowed = {
      '2012-07-24': 1,
      '2012-08-14': 1,
      '2012-08-21': 1,
      '2012-09-11': 1,
  '2012-09-18': 1,
      '2012-10-09': 1,
      '2012-10-16': 1
};
$("#" + webinarDate.id).datepicker({
    // called for every date before it is displayed
    beforeShowDay: function(date) {

        // prepend values lower than 10 with 0
        function addZero(no) {
            if (no < 10){
              return "0" + no;
            }  else {
              return no; 
            }
        }

        var date_str = [
            addZero(date.getFullYear()),
            addZero(date.getMonth() + 1),
            addZero(date.getDate())      
        ].join('-');

        if (dates_allowed[date_str]) {
            return [true, 'good_date', 'This date is selectable'];
        } else {
            return [false, 'bad_date', 'This date is NOT selectable'];
        }
    }
});
```

But problem is user can enter date in textbox instead of using datepicker(Which i dont want that). How to restrict the user to select date from datepicker instead entering manually. i hope you understand..

Comment: Must you use a datepicker?  If the only choices are 1st or 2nd Tuesday of the month, perhaps a dropdown would be a better choice?

Comment: Note: You need to also ensure you have server side validation to check the values and not rely purely on the field being disabled.

Comment: @TheZ "disabled" textbox's are not sent on a POST so readonly is the correct choice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**You mean this?**

You can set the datepicker input text as readonly using the following.

In your case will be to this element: `$("#" + webinarDate.id)`

---

```
<input type='text' id='datepickerTxt' readonly='true'>
```

Or:

```
$("#datepickerTxt").attr('readonly', 'true');
```

Or:

```
$("#datepickerTxt").keypress(function(e){ e.preventDefault(); });
```

In modern jQuery versions:

```
$("#datepickerTxt").prop('readonly', 'true');
```

Answer (score 0):

Is a date picker the correct solution here? It feels more like a dropdown list with the next lot of dates selectable.

If it needs to be then you can target user typing with an onblur and do your test.

Or if onfocus is triggered disable keyboard inputs.

Answer (score 0):

I would see this answer:
[jQuery Date Picker where text input is read only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2771137/jquery-date-picker-where-text-input-is-read-only)
Add an onclick event and disable the input

Answer (score 0):

in ASPX - Drag and drop the AJAX Calender Extender, Change ControlToValidate to ID of the txt_Date (date text box), Change Enable Client Script to False

Then

In The TextBox Property, Simply change the Read-Only property to TRUE..

(Make Sure You already drag the ScriptManager for the Extenders to Work)...

Now you could only change the date using the Calender Extender, hence invalid dates Could Not be entered..